# Simple jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to build a simple jQuery plugin, but I don't know how to start, I read a few articles and even tried to learn code of a few popular plugins, but it draw me even deeper into confusion.

Show me please a starter template. Let's say for the sake of example I should get something, that I can call like that:

```
 $("a").myMessagePlugin();
```

Now, everytime somebody clicks a link it should just popup an alert and show that link.

Thank you

Comment: It's probably not "how to create a plugin" that is holding you back but how to create it in javascript. You need to look at prototype extensions and how to declare functions that execute immediately after execution and other such great stuff to help you out...I too faced the same thing. Knowing the underlying javscript fundamentals will make your life MUCH EASIER :)

Comment: Oh yes, you'll be able to decipher existing plug-ins with ease to start you up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers are mostly correct, but if you want to use the dollar sign, wrap it in an anonymous function and pass the jQuery object.  Otherwise, you run the risk of conflicting with other libraries.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myMessagePlugin = function(options) {
        return this.click( function() { //jQuery object, to be returned
            alert(this.href); //html element
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you write a `jQuery` plugin make sure you return the `jQuery` object because it will help in chaining the `jQuery` methods.

```
$.fn.myMessagePlugin = function(options) {
    return this.each(function(){
        //plugin logic here
        $(this).click( function() { 
           alert(this.href);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: inner `this` is a `dom` object. The OP can write any logic inside the each block as per the plugin requirement.

Comment: @Agzam - Hope this helps you and make you understand how to begin writing a simple `jQuery` plugin

Answer (score 1):

it is recomended you specify undefined as well (I'm using previous example as base, thanks)

Also a good practice is to define defaults for the options and extend them using $.extend

```
(function($, undefined) {
    $.fn.myPlugin= function(options) {
        var opts = $.extend($.fn.myPlugin.defaults, options);

        return this.click( function() { //jQuery object, to be returned
            alert(this.href); //html element
        });
    }

    $.fn.myPlugin.defaults =  {
       "option1": 1,
       "option2": 2
    }
})(jQuery);
```